# Linker Error - file was built for unsupported file format

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I've been trying to solve this error.

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/abollba/Desktop/DataSiteOne-iOS/DynamicFrameworks/PDFNet.framework/PDFNet, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73 0x3A 0x2F 0x2F ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/abollba/Desktop/DataSiteOne-iOS/DynamicFrameworks/PDFNet.framework/PDFNet`

A number of people on my team are building this branch successfully.  I'm the only one with the problem.  We've all tried clone fresh repo's, fresh branches off the main develop, and all building the same commit, with the same Xcode version and OS version.  I'm the only one getting this error.

Given the way git works (you check out the state of the project) I don't see what could be special in my case.  Thats what I'm trying to find out.

Why might this be happening and what *should* i do to resolve it?

Comment: Hi!! Did you find a way to solve this? I'm having the exact same issue. Thanks

Comment: @CarlosPerezPerez if memory serves me, this was b/c we use git LFS to manage this large file.  i eventually tried logging out the contents of the binary of this framework and saw some git looking single line.  i then eventually stumbled upon 'git lfs pull'.  i logged the contents again and saw a bunch of binary gobbley-gook and the app linked up w/ the framework successfully.  hope that helps.